# Montar um script de informações similares (PHP, Procedure, etc.)

Tags: php

Em um banco de dados tenho informações cadastrais como:

- idade
- cor
- peso

Isso de cada pessoa cadastrada.

Como identificar pessoas que possuam dados exatamente iguais nesta base?

Na pratica:

- Edu, 46, branco, 70kg
- Bio, 46, branco, 70kg 
  --> isso deu igualdade  100%
  .
- Edu, 46, branco, 70kg
- Leo, 36, branco, 60kg 
  --> isso deu igualdade 80%

Então a primeira opção seria a desejada.

Comment: Você já tem sua função de comparação?

Comment: Em que momento ele deve fazer isso? É uma requisição do usuário?

Comment: Eu nao tenho a funcao de comparacao, está rotina pode rodar em segundo plano no banco (daí nao seria um PHP) , na verdade na pergunta coloquei PHP mas deveria ser PL\SQL ou Procedure

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que percebi quer fazer uma pesquisa a todos os usuarios e depois comparar as informações de cada.

Para isso precisa de ir buscar todos os usuários ao banco de dados.

Aqui pode ver tudo o que precisa de saber em mysql se for o caso para o PHP:

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysql.php

Depois a parte das comparações aconselho a fazer no php com recurso ás funções mysql_fetch_assoc entre outras para percorrer a informação e fazer as comparações devidas.

Comment: Pedro, obrigado pelo retorno, é o que eu preciso, mas preciso pelo menos da estrutura deste código PHP, pois não sei como começar, tanto que eu penso que parte desta função de comparação poderia ser feita pelo banco, ou não?

Comment: Acredito que seja mais dificil da parte do que do banco de dados já que o PHP pode transformar o select dos dados num array manipulavel